# Error MSB4226: Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

I was wondering if someone has ran into this problem as I have tried everything to fix. I have a DevOps build pipeline in Azure running visual studio 2015 version (which matches my local machine) and I am running into this error

**Error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found**

It builds perfectly fine on my machine. I have no idea why I cannot get this to build fine on DevOps.. and I haven't seen many questions about it. I  went ahead and changed the vb.proj file to reflect the following and it still did not work

````
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!--Add the below line to fix the project loading in VS 2017 -->
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <!--End -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />```
````

Comment: I've been battling this for months on end with no real results - especially on the build server. 
Recently we went from TFS2013 to DevOps 2020; exact same error. You are on the correct path. Its something with those import tags.

Comment: ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980909/microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-on-the-build-server-whats-your

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your project is referring to VS 2017 somewhere.
Double-check all your solution and proj files for any reference to VS 2017.

Try to enable debug mode and gather more info.